# Finding a Clean/Overdriven Fender Tone

Tags: electric-guitar, amplifiers, effects-pedal, stratocaster

I am trying to find this guitar tone, where it sounds solid and amped when clean, and, it seems like, when a player’s hitting harder gets very nice sounding overdrive.

Like the telecaster in this video.

Everything I tried so far can’t achieve this amp overdrive - it sounds too dirty, and loosy.
Could you give any advice on achieving the tone?

Comment: You might get more helpful info if you describe what set up you have been using.

Comment: Two key things missing here. What pedals he might be using, and what amp/guitar/pedals you have available. It looks like he goes through a Marshall, but it ain't necessarily so. Guitarists have been known to use other amps/speakers from sponsors, but in sponsors' cabs!

Comment: One problem with trying to replicate guitar tones that we hear in live shows and recordings is that it’s not just the guitar, pedals, and amp we are hearing. The miking, mike preamp, and processing (compression, EQ, etc) can be a very big part of the final sound. Usually it’s better to experiment with your own gear to find its best sounds.

Comment: Don’t ask us, ask Jake. A quick search of “Jake Bugg guitar rig” turned up this, which might be informative: https://equipboard.com/pros/jake-bugg.  Also this video where he demonstrates some of his techniques: https://youtu.be/JVDFxP4XoMQ. Plenty more to discover, I’m sure.

Answer (score 1):

Your start point on a vintage amp [I started on a Marshall but ended up with a Vox] is "everything on 7" & work from there.
Modern hi-gain amp you'd have to pull everything back a long way, but I never use hi-gain amps because they don't suit anything I ever play. I tried a hi-gain Marshall & it was still too fuzzy with input on 3. I quickly abandoned it - it was never going to work.
Guitar on full volume & tone.

After that it depends on your guitar's pickup output, brightness, string gauge & how hard you hit it.

Also, I'd have guessed 'front [or middle] pickup' from that sound - but he doesn't appear to have one… Pickup selector is at the back, but there's nothing visible at the front. There's no guessing what pickup that is. It looks like a standard tele/strat [& you can read the Fender on the headstock at some points in the video], but who knows. Tellys are always brighter & twangier than Strats on the back pickup anyway [strats can get a bit 'barky' on the back], which is probably what confuses my ears on that. I've never owned a real Telly.

[image]

Testing on my Variax through the different tele models, I'm finding I get closer to that sound with an old Vox AC30 with treble boost than I can with a Marshall. Gain about 7 [no numbers on a Vox] treble right up. If I recall correctly, old Voxes used to only reduce treble, not add it, which is why there's a modded model with increased top end, just nice for this sound.

As noted in comments above, the resulting sound you hear is not just 'a guitar & an amp' it's everything else between player & recording. One fun thing about modelling amps [& guitars] is you have a million things to play with. You can change the mic model, orientation & distance; change the speaker cab independently of the amp… add pedals of a myriad sorts, compressors & reverbs - lots of tweaks.

*From the deleted answer/comment.*
I use modelling for everything [except for one Strat]. Guitar is an original Line 6 Variax 500 from around 2004. Amps are again Line 6, Amp Farm.
I did have brief flirtations with other amp modelling structures, Guitar Rig, Amplitube etc - which were good but had various annoyances with updates sounding different or not being compatible, they also have some latency which the Line6 doesn't - so I went back to the Amp Farm.
Some might say, "Ooh, but is it quite as good as the real thing?"
Maybe not but if I can't tell the difference in the studio, no-one will by the time the track's finished.
Plus… I've got perhaps 50 grand's worth of guitars & amps for about 650 quid/bucks/euros.

*Late, late edit*
Further research tells me the 'single pickup tele' is actually an Esquire, precorsor to the Tele & is being made again. The pickup selector is a routing cvontrol for the tone aspects - see https://planetbotch.blogspot.com/2020/05/why-does-fender-esquire-have-pickup-selector-switch.html and
https://www.fender.com/articles/gear/70th-anniversary-esquire

Comment: I'm interested to find out what the pup switch could be for...

Comment: Yeah, I wondered that too. Might even be a stacked humbucker in there, "quarter-pounder" style, with switching/phase options. That was part of my 'looks like a standard strat PU but can't tell by looking'. I used to have a quarter pounder in the back of my strat [fatter magnets but otherwise looked like a regular] but now have a hot rails instead, which you can tell by looking.

Comment: Looks just like the bridge pup on my Tele, but you could be right. Not like a Strat pup, I think.

Comment: @Tim - I can't tell the difference between regular strat & tele rear pickups just by looking, though apparently Fender do consider them different. https://www.fender.com/articles/how-to/asked-answered-the-difference-between-strat-and-tele-bridge-pickups [well, tele pickups have three mount points, not two]

Comment: That was my thought. Not easy to mount a 2 screw  Strat pup into the Tele 'ashtray'. I guess the angles of the two differ, but that's not an issue.  Aren't most Strat pups white? (He asked naiively).

Comment: Mainly, but not always. I've a black strat with black pickups, the others are all white. With the covers off, though, they're all black.